# Make button left of input

Tags: html, css

I want to make button with id `#searchBtn` left to input form with id `#searchInput`.
HTML:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.searchInputMain {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
}

.searchButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#searchForm {
  position: static;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 500px;
}

#searchBtn {
  position: static;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="searchForm">
    <form>
      <input class="searchInputMain">
      <button class="searchButton" id="searchBtn" type="submit">
                        Search
                    </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

How to make it? Which styles need to it? Which styles is useless?

Comment: Can't you just switch elements in place?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: Just switch the position of button and input elements. Remove margin-right on the button. Hurrayyy!!! It will work

Answer (score 1):

- Just switch position in `html`.
- **removed unnecessary css.**

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.searchInputMain {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
}

.searchButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
}

#searchForm {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#searchForm form {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="searchForm">
    <form>
      <button class="searchButton" id="searchBtn" type="submit">
                        Search
                    </button>
      <input class="searchInputMain">
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .searchInputMain {
      width: 300px;
      height: 40px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .searchButton {
      width: 200px;
      height: 40px;
    }

    form{
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="searchForm">
    <form>
      <input class="searchInputMain">
      <button class="searchButton" id="searchBtn" type="submit">
                        Search
                    </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

a better way would be to simply change the HTML to position the button before the form element. but if you can not do that, replace your CSS with the following one

```
    header {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .searchInputMain {
      width: 300px;
      height: 40px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .searchButton {
      width: 200px;
      height: 40px;
    }

    form{
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
```